# How to set the value of ASP.NET control

Tags: c#, asp.net

**A little background**

I have built my own localization mechanism, basically it goes like this:

- I have an XML file which stores all the strings in each language
- I am parsing and storing the values from the XML within the `Application` object when the application starts

Now to set **None** asp control i am using this line of code:

```
<div><%= Application["New-Permission-Role"].ToString() %></div>
```

But i can't use this syntax on ASP.NET controls.

For example i am trying to localize the `HeaderText` property of a `GridView`

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText='<%= Application["Actions"].ToString() %>'>
```

I know it related to ASP.NET not rendering it

**Note:** I know i can populate it on the server side meaning at `.cs` file, but i wondering if there is a way to accomplish it on the aspx file?

---

**I already tried the following:**

Change the `<% = %>` to `<%# %>` to rise the data bindings and i am getting an compilation error
`Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField does not have a DataBinding event`.

**Solution**
I was followed @roman_m advice and i created a custom expression using this [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125044/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx#postadlink)
as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394060/set-templatefield-headertext-dynamic-for-localization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `=` with `#` to trigger databinding:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText='<%# Application["Actions"].ToString() %>'>
```

Comment: already tried it and i am getting a error Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField does not have a DataBinding event.

Comment: @silagy I guess this answers your question

Comment: @silagy have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394060/set-templatefield-headertext-dynamic-for-localization